# streaming into a bokeh varea_stack

Tags: plot, bokeh

I am trying to use the `varea_stack` and be able to stream data into it. To create it, I use the following code:

```
self.limits_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[], normal=[], amber=[], red=[], top=[]))
self._stack_graph = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_both', toolbar_location=None, tools="")
self._stack_graph.varea_stack(['normal', 'amber', 'red', 'top'], x='x', color=("green", "orange", "red"),
                               source=self.limits_source)
```

My idea is to then use a callback to populate this data source as data comes in.

However, this code results in the error:

```
File "/anaconda2/envs/pred/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/plotting/figure.py", line 1131, in varea_stack
    for kw in _double_stack(stackers, "y1", "y2", **kw):
  File "/anaconda2/envs/pred/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/plotting/helpers.py", line 144, in _double_stack
    raise ValueError("Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must be the same length as stackers")
ValueError: Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must be the same length as stackers
```

The error seems to suggest it requires this "y1" and "y2" areas i.e. onl;y two stackable areas. Is that true? i.e. Can I  only have 2 stacks?

Answer (score 1):

No, that error means if you are stacking N bars, then you have to have e.g. exactly N colors (or whatever property) to match.  Your code stacks 4 things:

```
['normal', 'amber', 'red', 'top']
```

but only provides 3 colors:

```
("green", "orange", "red")
```

That does not match up, and cannot work.